# How to add sorting symbols in my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add sorting symbols to my HTML table. 
Below is my Javascript code.

```
function sortTableRowsByColumn( table, columnIndex, ascending ) {

    const rows = Array.from( table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > tbody > tr' ) );

    rows.sort( ( x, y ) => {

        const xValue = x.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
        const yValue = y.cells[columnIndex].textContent;

        const xNum = parseFloat( xValue );
        const yNum = parseFloat( yValue );

        return ascending ? ( xNum - yNum ) : ( yNum - xNum );
    } );

    for( let row of rows ) {
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild( row );
    }
}

function onColumnHeaderClicked( ev ) {

    const th = ev.currentTarget;
    const table = th.closest( 'table' );
    const thIndex = Array.from( th.parentElement.children ).indexOf( th );

    const ascending = !( 'sort' in th.dataset ) || th.dataset.sort != 'asc';

    sortTableRowsByColumn( table, thIndex, ascending );

    const allTh = table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > thead > tr > th' );
    for( let th2 of allTh ) {
        delete th2.dataset['sort'];
    }

    th.dataset['sort'] = ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc';
}
```

Here is my html for table.

```
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" style="font-size: 50%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th onclick="onColumnHeaderClicked(event)" scope="col">Klant  </th>
        <th scope="col">Adres</th>
        <th onclick="onColumnHeaderClicked(event)" scope="col"># panelen</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

My sorting works completely fine. However, to make it more intuitive, i want to add sorting symbols to my header. Can some one suggest a way to do it?

Comment: You can use some libraries as font awesome icons, materialize, eva icons etc to have your symbol or you can simply use an img. 
An idea of doing it, it's when you sort (ASC) you show the asc icon and hide the desc icon and vice versa or you can use rotate to rotate your icon to 180°.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments you can use icons and fonts. It is also possible to use the UTF-8 character set to add a character to your column heading. The following two are useful for this purpose:

- `&#x25b4;` which will display as ▴
- `&#x25be;` which will display as ▾

Depending on whether the column is unsorted, sorted ascending or sorted descending you display one of the following three variants:

1. `<tr>Klant &#x25b4;&#x25be;</tr>` which will look like Klant ▴▾
2. `<tr>Klant &#x25b4</tr>` which will look like Klant ▴
3. `<tr>Klant &#x25be;</tr>` which will look like Klant ▾